# finding the pattern (ab)* using grep

Tags: command-line, grep

```
grep ab* filename.txt
```

The command above finds lines that start with `a` and end with any number of `b`'s. For example:

```
a
ab
abb
abb
```

But how do I fix my command so it finds lines like these?

```
ab
abab
abababab
```

I tried `grep (ab)* filename.txt`, but it won't do it because it's the same as `(ab | (ab) | (ab))`.

Comment: Are you just asking how to use parentheses as grouping characters instead of literals? If so, you either escape them `grep '\(ab\)*'` or use extended regular expression (ERE) mode `grep -E '(ab)*'` . BTW always quote your REs (so the shell doesn't try to glob match them to files in the current directory).

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> grep (ab)* filename.txt
> ```
>
> The one above won't do it because it's the same as (ab | (ab) | (ab)).

No, it won't work because `()` is special for most shells and you'll get a syntax error:

```
$ grep (ab)* foo
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

## Quote your expressions.

Now, `grep` uses Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) by default. To group part of an expression in BRE, you need to use `\(...\)`:

```
$ echo xababx | grep -o '\(ab\)*'
abab
```

Or use Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) or Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE), where `(...)` is enough:

```
$ echo abab | grep -Eo '(ab)*'
abab
$ echo abab | grep -Po '(ab)*'
abab
```

See [`grep` manual for BRE vs ERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ more ~/tmp/test_grep.txt
ab
abab
abababab
abaab
aba

$ grep -e '^\(ab\)\+$' ~/tmp/test_grep.txt
ab
abab
abababab
```

`-e` option is to use regular expression.
The expression is `^(ab)+$` by which the `^` start at the beginning of line, the `+` tells to repeat the group `(ab)` and the `$` tell to end after `(ab)`.