# using repetition ranges {} with grep

Tags: command-line, grep

```
$ grep a{2,} alphabet.txt
grep: a: No such file or directory
$cat alphabet.txt
abcdefghijklnmopqrstuvwxyz
```

My alphabet.txt contains a line with a through z.
Doesn't a{2,} mean match aaa*? However, the `grep` isn't even working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding the pattern (ab)\* using grep](http://askubuntu.com/questions/876735/finding-the-pattern-ab-using-grep)

Comment: What do you mean with "isn't even working" ?

Answer (score 16):

*Escape your Regex pattern to avoid shell interpretation beforehand.*

You have used the pattern `a{2,}`, without any escaping, as this is a valid `bash` brace expansion pattern it is being expanded by `bash` as `a2 a`.

So eventually what `grep` gets is:

```
grep a2 a alphabet.txt
```

As the file `a` does not exist hence the error regarding it.

---

Just escape the pattern using any of the usual manners:

```
grep 'a{2,}' alphabet.txt
grep "a{2,}" alphabet.txt
grep a\{2,\} alphabet.txt
```

Here, using the single quotes is advised unless you have a variable you want to expand -- in that case use double quotes. Try to avoid the backslash escaping as that might garbled up patterns and make them unreadable e.g. while escaping ERE (Extended Regular Expression) tokens within BRE (Basic Regular Expression); where you'll need to (blackslash) escape twice to make the engine treat them as ERE tokens.

---

Even now, the braces would be treated literally because `grep` by default uses BRE engine while the range matching with `{}` is actually an ERE token. So you can use `-E` option to treat the pattern as ERE:

```
grep -E 'a{2,}' alphabet.txt
```

Or escape the braces within BRE:

```
grep 'a\{2,\}' alphabet.txt
```

---

As a side note, your input file does not contain two or more successive `a`'s, hence the pattern `a{2,}` will never match with the current input.

Comment: Explaining to this user seems pointless. They have been told before to quote their expressions. http://askubuntu.com/q/876735/158442

Comment: muru, won't waste any more time :/

Comment: @muru :D Voted to close as a duplicate! (After upvoting)

Comment: @Fabby hehe..BTW how's everything?

Comment: @heemayl drop by in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)